# change the background of a border when checkbox ischecked

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i am able to change the color of border background using checked event and manually changing background color every-time radio button is checked/unchecked , but i want to achieve the same using converter or visual states manager or any other efficient way, so how to achieve it .here is the xaml

```
    <Border x:Name="br1" Background="Blue" >
         <RadioButton Checked="radio1_Checked"  x:Name="radio1" />
    </Border>

     <Border x:Name="br2" Background="Blue" >
         <RadioButton Checked="radio2_Checked"  x:Name="radio2" />
      </Border>
```

i want to change the color of border background whenever radio-button is checked and unchecked so how to achieve it

Comment: Converters are definitely not 'efficient'

Comment: i want to just change the color every time radio-button is checked and unchecked , so what else can be the best way @kyriacos_k

Answer (score 1):

There are several different solutions possible, depending on the amount of work, flexibility and re-usability you're looking after.

*EDIT: Code below is for Windows (Phone) 8.1 RT and not for Windows Phone Silverlight. Leaving it here for future reference though, as Silverlight will be replaced by Windows Runtime on Windows 10 anyway.*

As the standard `RadioButton` already has a border built-in its visual tree, and for highest flexibility and re-usability I've created a custom control (called *Templated Control* in Visual Studio item templates) derived from the `RadioButton`.

I provided a `CheckedBrush` and `UncheckedBrush` (default Red/Transparent) so you can customize to your wish. Setting one of these values in XAML will override the default values.

The code of the custom control:

```
public sealed class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public MyRadioButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyRadioButton);
        UnCheckedBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        CheckedBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        this.Checked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.CustomBackground = CheckedBrush;
        };
        this.Unchecked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.CustomBackground = UnCheckedBrush;
        };
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CustomBackground", typeof (Brush), typeof (MyRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CheckedBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnCheckedBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "UnCheckedBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

    public Brush CustomBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue(CustomBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush CheckedBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue(CheckedBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckedBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush UnCheckedBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush) GetValue(UnCheckedBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UnCheckedBrushProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Next step is providing the style in the Themes/Generic.xaml file, this is a slightly tweaked style (for the background) from the default RadioButton style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyRadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonContentForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,4,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyRadioButton">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding CustomBackground}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonContentDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="29" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse"
                                     Width="23"
                                     Height="23"
                                     UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                     Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                     Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                     StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                                     Width="13"
                                     Height="13"
                                     UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                     Opacity="0"
                                     Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                                       Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                                       Width="29"
                                       Height="29" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                                       Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                                       Width="29"
                                       Height="29" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The only things changed from the default template is dropping the Background property and changing the Background on the Border control.

You're all set to use it:

```
<StackPanel Margin="100">
    <RadioButton Content="Check 1" />
    <local:MyRadioButton CheckedBrush="Blue" Content="Check 2" />
    <local:MyRadioButton CheckedBrush="Green" Content="Check 3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: so i will create new user control than add your cs code ,than in xaml do i need to put radio button there? and where to put this style xaml you created @Bart

Comment: Create a new templated control. This will add a Themes/Generic.xaml file where the style has to come, and a control.cs file where the control code has to come.

Comment: i tried your way than  i am getting error on ThemeResource as it is not available for windows phone 8 silver-light, so i cannot use your solution @Bart

Comment: Ah Windows Phone 8 SL, my bad. The code above is for WP 8.1 RT (which also works on Windows). You can edit the existing RadioButton style and add in the border. However on my pc the Checked mark isn't drawn, and I don't have the right tools on this machine to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a view-model class (see [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)) and implement two DependencyPropery's one with the checkbox-state and one with the border-color. Bind the corresponding XAML attributes to these properties using data-binding. When checkbox-state changes also raise the PropertyChanged event for the border color. Done.